# How to destroy Session after page load?

Tags: php, session

I want to show a session variable in a web page and if the web page get reloaded it will destroy the session means user can't see the same message if he reload the same webpage.

for that I have used the following procedure using PHP

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
} 
session_unset();
?>
```

But when i reload the same page again I saw the following Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: message

Can anyone suggest me what can be the procedure so that I can ignore the notice

Comment: You've written a conditional to print a variable only if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code this should solve your query

if session is not destroyed 'hello' message will not be shown.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['message']='hello';
  if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
       echo $_SESSION['message'];
       } 
    unset($_SESSION);

//test
echo $_SESSION['message'];
?>
```

Comment: try now you have spelling mistake @User57

Comment: I'm not sure because when I remove the `!` symbol before `isset` I don't see the message! sound strange but that's what happening

Comment: it means session is destroyed! hope you have corrected your  mistake of ' '$_SESSION['messsage'] ' which should be $_SESSION['message']

Comment: @User57 previously the session which you was checking is different and the session which you destroyed  was not the same due to the spelling mistake! hope that solved your query

Comment: @User57 check the code updated if hello prints the session exists else if destroyed it will trow an error.

Comment: There is a Typo you have also ie, it shouldn't be `if(!isset(` it should be `if(isset(`

Comment: Remove the `!` before isset and i will accept the answer.

Comment: @User57 check now

Answer (score 2):

Update     if condition

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['messsage'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['message'];       
   } 
  session_unset();
 ?>
```

Comment: then I don't see the message

Comment: we are displaying session value before destroying, value will be display only it is set. or you can store value in another variable and then echo it and then do unset session. you can use this too to unset session e.g. unset($_SESSION['message'])

Answer (score 0):

as you can know that the code runs line to line so if you have any condition where you want to destroy the session, put `session_destroy();` there, otherwise you can put it at the last line of your code. it is the last point where your goes.

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This :

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Hello";
    if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        session_destroy();
    }
```